# Linq to XML Question

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Given the following XML, what query can I use to extract the value of preapprovalKey to a string variable? Still a little new to LINQ to XML.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <ns2:PreapprovalResponse xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
- <responseEnvelope>
  <timestamp>2011-04-05T18:35:32.952-07:00</timestamp> 
  <ack>Success</ack> 
  <correlationId>7cec030fa3eb2</correlationId> 
  <build>1655692</build> 
  </responseEnvelope>
  <preapprovalKey>PA-9AG427954Y7578617</preapprovalKey> 
  </ns2:PreapprovalResponse>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, long day. Post edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
string preapprovalKey = doc.Descendants("preapprovalKey").Single().Value;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

See below my exmaple, it help you to resolve your issue and problem. :)

Consider this below XML is there as one of the SQL table's column.

```
<Root>
<Name>Dinesh</Name>
<Id>2</Id>
</Root>
```

The objective of the query is to fetch the Name from the XML. In this example we will fetch the 'Dinesh' as the value.

```
   var Query = (from t in dbContext.Employee.AsEnumerable()
    where t.active == true 
    select new Employee
    {
    Id = t.AtpEventId,  
    Name = XDocument.Parse(t.Content).Descendants("Root").Descendants("Name").ToList().  
    Select(node => node.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()  
    });
```

Note the following :-

1. Here in above LINQ , t.active == true is just an example to make some condition if needed.
2. Please note, in the above LInQ query, always use the AsEnumerable(), as I did in the
   first file of the Linq query.exmaple(var Query = (from t in dbContext.Employee.AsEnumerable())
3. Descendants("**Root**").Descendants("**Name**") , Here Root should be the Element matching with the XML, And under the Root we have Name element, thats why we wrote 
   Descendants("**Root**").Descendants("**Name**")
4. For any further clarification you can reach me via danish.eggericx@gmail.com