# Get XElement from XML using LINQ

Tags: xml, linq

I have a file path already load into XDocument. I am trying to get XElement but not find any good source.

Is it possible to get XElement tag using LINQ to XML?

An **XML** looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transactionBlock>
    <trans aux ID="1849" company ID="ABC">
        <T.2.12.0>
            <event TS>16:02:56Z</event TS>
            <equipment ID="0105449160" mobile Type="2" equip Type="tractor"/>
            <driver ID>002</driver ID>
        </T.2.12.0>
    </trans>
    <trans aux ID="1854" company ID="XYZ">
        <T.2.06.0>
            <event TS>16:07:50Z</event TS>
            <equipment ID="0105449160" mobile Type="3"/>
            <driver ID>002</driver ID>
        </T.2.06.0>
    </trans>
</transactionBlock>
```

Comment: XML Sample:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <transaction Block>

    <trans aux ID="1849" company ID="ABC">
    <T.2.12.0>
     <event TS>16:02:56Z</event TS>
     <equipment ID="0105449160" mobile Type="2" equip Type="tractor"/>
     <driver ID>002</driver ID>
    </T.2.12.0>
    </trans>

    <trans aux ID="1854" company ID="XYZ">
    <T.2.06.0>
     <event TS>16:07:50Z</event TS>
     <equipment ID="0105449160" mobile Type="3"/>
     <driver ID>002</driver ID>
    </T.2.06.0>
    </trans>

       </transaction Block>

Comment: which element you want , just use XDocumentInstance.Root.Elements() will give all the elements.

Comment: I only want <T.2.12.0>,<T.2.06.0>. I am passing these values as XElement to function later.

Comment: Have you attempted any research?  LINQ to XML is very well documented and there are tons of examples - here's just one from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5560720/745969

Comment: transaction Block is not valid xml element name.
XML elements must follow these naming rules:

Element names are case-sensitive
Element names must start with a letter or underscore
Element names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
Element names can contain letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, and periods
Element names cannot contain spaces
Any name can be used, no words are reserved (except xml).
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Comment: @Tim I have attempted a lot of research. I found very good examples to get XElement attribute value but not find any good example for my scenario.

Comment: @Dreamweaver This is the xml format I need to work on it. This is just small snapshot from original file. There is no space between transactionblock. I inserted spaces to provide ease in reading.

Comment: @user2229874 - It's a pretty basic task, to read an element or attribute with LINQ to XML.  What about your scenario makes it unworkable?  Can you post a sample of the code you've tried?

Comment: @Tim How to check value should not be null in the LINQ to XML query?                                                                                                                 var doc = XDocument.Load(File);
        var transactions = doc.Root.Elements().Select(t => t.Elements().First());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> transactions = doc.Root.Descendants("trans").Where(x => string.Compare(x.Name.LocalName, "trans") == 0 && x.HasElements).Select(x => (x.FirstNode as XElement).Name.LocalName);
                foreach (var item in transactions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);     
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I find easier to navigate in XML elements using XPath expressions, as it can deal with filters and a more direct approach to the existing structure. In this case, you could do like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <transactionBlock>
        <trans auxID='1849' companyID='ABC'>
            <T.2.12.0>
                <eventTS>16:02:56Z</eventTS>
                <equipment ID='0105449160' mobileType='2' equipType='tractor'/>
                <driverID>002</driverID>
            </T.2.12.0>
        </trans>
        <trans auxID='1854' companyID='XYZ'>
            <T.2.06.0>
                <eventTS>16:07:50Z</eventTS>
                <equipment ID='0105449160' mobileType='3'/>
                <driverID>002</driverID>
            </T.2.06.0>
        </trans>
    </transactionBlock>");

var transactions = doc.XPathSelectElements("/transactionBlock/trans/*");
foreach (var transaction in transactions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(transaction.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will helps someone:

Solution:

```
       var doc = XDocument.Load(File);
        var transactions = doc.Root.Elements().Select(t => t.Elements().First());

        foreach (var transaction in transactions)
        {
            var id = transaction.Name.LocalName;
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
```

Output:

T.2.12.0

T.2.06.0

Comment: if any case there is no element inside the t, then calling t,First() will throw an exception "Sequence Contains no element."

Comment: @Dreamweaver Thank you for sharing your solution. In my case, we always have an element.